# A Little Beyond Selecting Two Tables in MYSQL with PHP or a JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a `SELECT` from two tables in the same db. This is what I'm trying...

```
SELECT * FROM Orders O
JOIN Employees_Packers EP
O.PackedBy AS EP.UserName
WHERE O.Shipped = 0 ORDER BY Order_ID
```

I'm trying to get this `SELECT` to give me all the rows where `Shipped = 0` and have the `EP.UserName` value to show instead of the `O.PackedBy`. What am I missing?

`EP.UserName` = a Name Value

`O.PackedBy` = an Number

Comment: There has to be a relationship between the Orders and Employees_Packers like a EP.id that is being refered to by O.PackedBy perhaps? Then join on that premise because the natural join that you are doing is a cross join.

Comment: EP.UserName is the Name for the O.PackedBy, O.PackedBy is the same value as EP.Packer_ID

Comment: The error I get is `encountered an error.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'O.PackedBy = EP.UserName WHERE O.Shipped = 0 ORDER BY Order_ID' at line 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If O.PackedBy was also a string, this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders O
JOIN Employees_Packers EP
ON O.PackedBy = EP.UserName
WHERE O.Shipped = 0 ORDER BY Order_ID
```

But I'm guessing that O.PackedBy is a Foreign Key to EP.ID (whatever the unique id field is named).  Try substituting EP.UserName with EP.ID.

EDIT:

OK - given the comment below:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders O
JOIN Employees_Packers EP
ON O.PackedBy = EP.Packer_ID
WHERE O.Shipped = 0 ORDER BY Order_ID
```

This should join your two tables.  `SELECT *` will give you all of the fields in both tables.  If you only want EP.UserName in the result, replace the * with EP.Username.

Comment: With EP.Packer_ID instead of EP.UserName, how would I have it display the EP.UserName over the EP.Packer_ID?